# How to custom list inside of selectfield of Sencha Touch app?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I would like to custom the list of the selectfield in a Sencha Touch app, for example I need to indicate `variableHeight` parameter because I have texts very long..

Thank you

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? 1. you have a list. 2. you have a selectfield. 3. where is the list and where is the selectfield? 4. can you post your view?

Comment: Meanly when I tap on the selectfield appears a modal list by default in ST, my idea is modify width for each item dynamically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1
you need to add a custom css to your selectfield-list.

a) onFocus of the selectfield you need to change the width of the listPanel

```
onFocus: function (e) {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.listPanel.setWidth(180);
}
```

OR

a) get the selectfield when the listPanel is shown

```
sf = Ext.Viewport.down('selectfield[action=mySelectfield]');
```

b) set the width of the panel

```
sf.listPanel.setWidth(180)
```

OR

use css:

```
.x-select-overlay{
    .x-list {
        x-list-item {
            ---> here goes your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect... Works!!